# Deployed Laravel app can't handle variables passed to controller via Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, nginx, vps, php-7.3

I created a Laravel app in my local environment and it works just fine. When I deployed it to a **VPS** server, for accessing it online, for some reason, my **AJAX stopped working**. Here's an example of a very simple AJAX function which works in local, but **doesn't work in my server.**

The **view**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax Example</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>
        function getMessage() {
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/getmsg',
                data: {
                    greeting: 'Hello'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#msg").html(data.msg);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax.
    Click the button to replace the message.
</div>
<?php
echo Form::button('Replace Message', ['onClick' => 'getMessage()']);
?>
</body>

</html>
```

The **controller**:

```
class TestAjaxController extends Controller {
    public function index(Request $request) {
        return response()->json(array('msg'=> $request->greeting), 200);
    }
}
```

The **route**:

```
//Test routes
Route::get('ajax-test',function() {
    return view('ajax-test');
});
Route::get('/getmsg','TestAjaxController@index');
```

All this function does, is by clicking a button it send a defined variable to the controller and the the controller returns a response with the same message to the view and then Jquery changes the text to the message.

The problem is when the button is pressed no **data** is being passed to the controller, so the controller **returns empty array**.

Note: My local environment uses Apache (XAMPP), but my VPS uses NGINX. Altho I doubt it is the problem here.

I am totally lost in what could be wrong. Maybe there are some PHP modules missing from my VPS install or something similar?

Comment: Take a look in your browser's developer tools network panel. Inspect the request to make sure the data's there, and the response (including its status code).

Comment: Did that. The _Request URL: http://*server is*/getmsg?greeting=Hello_ and the Response is `{"msg":null}`. But the same exact code in my local environment returns a response : `{"msg":"Hello"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for some reason i just needed to use `POST` methods. I don't know why everything was working locally with `GET`, but on production server I had to use `POST`.

Here is the working code:
View:

```
<script>
    function getMessage() {
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/getmsg',
            data: {
                greeting: 'Hello'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#msg").html(data.msg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The route:

```
Route::get('ajax-test',function() {
    return view('ajax-test');
});
Route::post('/getmsg','TestAjaxController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually accessing form field. Straight from documentation

> **`Retrieving Input Via Dynamic Properties`**

You may also access user input using dynamic properties on the **Illuminate\Http\Request** instance. For example, if one of your application's forms contains a **name** field, you may access the value of the field like so:

```
$name = $request->name;
```

When using dynamic properties, Laravel will first look for the parameter's value in the request payload. If it is not present, Laravel will search for the field in the route parameters.

So try using `$request->query('name')` e.g `TestAjaxController` should be

```
class TestAjaxController extends Controller {
    public function index(Request $request) {
        return response()->json(array('msg'=> $request->query('greeting')), 200);
    }
}
```

I didn't test but it should work. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: It works just fine in the Local server, just like the example i provided, but it doesn't work in the deployed app.

Comment: @KiprasBielinskas did you try hit the URL directly & see the response? Does that work?

Comment: the dynamic property checks the input source and query string, then falls back to the route parameter